using third party script with NextJS
I am trying to load the a property (gradio-app) from a third party script. However, the gradio-app is not rendered in the page.
https://www.gradio.app/guides/sharing-your-app#embedding-hosted-spaces
import Script from 'next/script'

export default async function Gradio() {
    return (
        <>
            <Script
                type="module"
                src="https://gradio.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/4.36.1/gradio.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
            <gradio-app src="https://multimodalart-hallo.hf.space"></gradio-app>
        </>
    )
}

There is no error in the console when I load this page.
I did a test. I wrote a pure html file without using nextJS. The app is loaded properly.
I am clueless of what is going wrong.
Any help is appreciated.
To reproduce this problem:

You can create an empty NextJS project by runing: npx create-next-app@latest
Delete the content in the /app/page.tsx file.
paste the following code into the file:

import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
        <Script type= "module" src = "https://gradio.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/4.36.1/gradio.js" strategy = "beforeInteractive" />
        <gradio-app src = "https://multimodalart-hallo.hf.space" > </gradio-app>
        < />
    )
}


start the server by npm run dev
Launch the homepage. You should see that the gradio app is not loaded. This is a problem.


Personally I've had bad luck trying to use Web Components in Next.js, but how about using an iframe?
<iframe src = "https://multimodalart-hallo.hf.space" />

I tried it out and it works, you'd have to style it up a bit to show it in the appropriate dimensions. Other than that, I don't think there's any downside to using this instead of the Web Component.

Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, I did try with iframe and it was working for me. The problem is that I want to have more flexibility with the web components, for example to change the theme (dark mode).
